# If $A$ is a negative number, and $B = 0 - A^2$. Is $B$ a negative number or a positive number?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> If $A$ is a negative number, and $B = 0 - A^2$. Is $B$ a negative number or a positive number?

My first guess would be that B is a negative number.

Comment: That might be right, and it might be wrong. But more importantly, _why_ is that your guess? Do you have a _reason_?

Comment: Here's a tutorial on [mathjax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Using mathjax really helps in the readability of the question...

Comment: Also what is your approach to conclude that $B$ is negative?

Answer (score 1):

if $A$ is a negative imaginary number, with no real part, e.g.,$A=-i$, then $B$ will be positive

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginary_number

note that $A=\sqrt{-B}$ and check section "Square roots of negative numbers" in the wikipage above for the fallacies that one must pay attention to when dealing with square roots of negative numbers

Answer (score 1):

If we're dealing with real numbers, the square of **any** real number is always positive.(Check the graph of $y=x^2$). Since $B=-A^2 ,\  B$ is destined to be negative.
On the other hand, if we're dealing with [imaginary numbers](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Imaginary_number) (number is in the form of $ki$ where $k\neq 0$, $k \in \mathbb{R}$) , $A^2$ is, by definition, negative. This makes $B$ forever positive.

Comment: are you sure? all real numbers are imaginary. so, it is not true that if A is imaginary, A^2 is negative. A could be, for instance, A=1, right?

Comment: edited my answer to make it clear

Comment: @DanielS. I think you are confusing imaginary and complex numbers. All real numbers are complex numbers, with imaginary parts of zero.

Comment: indeed, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

- Note that as a general rule , $ (M-N)$ is the additive inverse of $(N-M)$, meaning that

$$(N-M)+ (M-N) = 0$$

or ( equivalently)

$$( M-N) = - (N-M)$$.

Also, note that ( leaving aside the case of $0$) , the additive inverse of a number $N$ , that is $(-N)$ has a sign opposite to the sign of $N$.

- Now, suppose that $A\neq 0$, we can reason like this :

(1) $(A^2 - 0)$ is a positive number since $(A^2 - 0) = A^2$ and $A^2$ is always positive.

(2) $(0 - A^2)$ is the additive inverse of $(A^2 - 0)$ , i.e. : $(0 - A^2)= - (A^2 - 0)$

(3) Therefore $(0 - A^2)$ is negative.

- This is true for any number $A ( \neq 0)$; so, *in particular*, it is true in case $A \lt 0$